# User and email friendly links in your communication with your users

Tags: php, email, cakephp, url-rewriting

Sometimes you need to send to your user activation links or links to their profile or links to some assets that may be buried deep into your application structure or folder structure.

The temptation is to quickly create a link like this one:

`http://example.com/index.php?controller=users&action=activate&profile_id=123023&token=a2ad2a1adaawda&goto=user_profile`

If you display that link on a HTML page, behind an `<A>` element then all is OK, but if you need to email this link to the user you run into some trouble.

If you're lucky and the email client of the user renders HTML then you can hide that behind an `<A>`. Otherwise you will have to send it as plain text and it may get broken into multiple lines or make only partially clickable by the email client, making it frustrating for the users to click on it, or to copy/paste it in their browsers.

What are the solutions to this?

I've detailed below how I've solved this problem recently and I welcome other solutions as well.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question is written with PHP, CakePHP and Apache mod_rewrite in mind, but the principles here can be applied to other web platforms as well.

The solution I've finally used was to leverage the Router in CakePHP (or if that is missing just use mod_rewrite from Apace, usually by editing .htaccess files).

**Suggestion: use short URLs**

The basic principle here is to use in your communication with your users (especially in emails) very short links, that looks nice and are under 80 characters (if possible) to avoid wrapping.

So instead of sending the really long and ugly URL:

`http://example.com/index.php?controller=users&action=activate&profile_id=123023&token=a2ad2a1adaawda&goto=user_profile`

send something like:

`http://example.com/activate_a2dra2bc430a11af`

This is much shorter, and most likely correctly rendered in email clients and if not pretty easy to copy/paste.

**So how do we convert back and forth between the two.**

The solutions vary depending on your choice of platforms.

If you do not have a *Router* implementation, you will have to rely on your `.htaccess` configuration to convert a short URL to the corresponding long URL.

However, if you use something like CakePHP (or if you implement your own *Router*) you get much more powerful capabilities in how you format your links (that would be otherwise hard or impossible to configure with Apache's mod_rewrite).

**Here is how I've implemented it**

First I've connected a route (`routes.php`) that will intercept my short activation links:

```php
Router::connect( '/activate_:token', 
    array( 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'activate' ),
    array( 'pass' => array( 'token' ), 'token' => '(.*)' ) 
);
```

Next in my Users Controller I have this function (a general overview of what you need to do):

```php
public function activate( $token ){
    //TODO: 1. validate $token has expected format
    //TODO: 2. do a db backup to check this token is valid
    //TODO: 3. do required action (like mark user as active)
    //TODO: 4. if this is 'use once' then delete token from database to prevent further use of link
    //TODO: 5. redirect user to the appropriate location in your app
}
```

Following is a brief explanation of the controller action.

Tokens are previously generated as unique and stored into the database. Depending on your needs you may use a Token model for this, or simply use a `token` column in the User table (as I did).

Step 1: Validate your token. It's a good idea to make sure the token looks like a token. For example if you expect numbers only or hexadecimal values, validate against that!

Step 2: Do a db lookup to find the row with your token. This will help with two things: first you will make sure this is a token you've sent out and secondly: it will also find the user it's linked to! (if you have stored the token in the Users table or via joins).

Step 3: Do what you need to do. In my case I've activated the user, but you can do whatever: reset password, increase a counter, send other notifications...

Step 4: If this is a link that can be used *only once*, now is a good time to delete the token from the DB. This will make sure the link will not work again.

Step 5: Based on your action type, redirect the user to the proper location in your app. In my case to the user profile.

**Token Generation**

As I've said, for this to work tokens need to be unique. There are many ways to do it, depending on how secure your token needs to be, but for most cases something simple like this will work (CakePHP code):

```php
while( 1 ){
    $token = substr( md5( Configure::read( 'Security.salt' ) . rand(1,10000) . time() ), 0, 16 );
    //repeat until I get a unique token. You will most likely get a unique one from the first time!
    if( !token_exists( $token ) ){
        break;
    }
}
```

**In Conclusion**

Using tokens like this:

- shortens the URLs making them email and user friendly
- adds a bit of security. It's more difficult to guess a valid token than to fiddle with the GET parameters in the original long URL
- this can be easily extended for permalinks and other actions

I hope you have found this informative and useful and that it gave you some ideas!

References:

- [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/) (thanks for a good [Router](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) implementation!)
- [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)